# GWT GoogleMaps Hide Default Layers Using Styles

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, gwt

I'm using GWT and the GWT GoogleMaps API ([v3.8.0](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list)). I have everything up and running perfectly.

However, I'd like to disable a few of the default features that come with GoogleMaps, such as street names, the ability to click on restaurants, etc. Basically I'd like a very barebones map layer that I add my own custom layers to.

I thought I could do this using Styles. I'm trying to use a MapTypeStyler with visibility off with a MapTypeStyle of whatever type I wanted to disable (in this test case, MapTypeStyle.ROAD).

Here is the test code I'm trying to get running:

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyle;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleElementType;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleFeatureType;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyler;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMap() {



        JsArray<MapTypeStyle> styles = (JsArray<MapTypeStyle>) JsArray.<MapTypeStyle>createArray();

        JsArray<MapTypeStyler> roadStylers = (JsArray<MapTypeStyler>) JsArray.<MapTypeStyler>createArray();
        MapTypeStyler roadStyler = MapTypeStyler.visibility("off");
        roadStylers.push(roadStyler);

        MapTypeStyle roadStyle = MapTypeStyle.create();
        roadStyle.setStylers(roadStylers);
        roadStyle.setFeatureType(MapTypeStyleFeatureType.ROAD); //this is line 43
        roadStyle.setElementType(MapTypeStyleElementType.ALL);

        styles.push(roadStyle);

        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mapOpts.setStreetViewControl(false);
        mapOpts.setStyles(styles);

        final GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);


    }
}
```

However, when I run that, I get an Exception:

```
14:49:52.756 [ERROR] [gwttest] Uncaught exception escaped

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.test.client.GwtTest.createMap(GwtTest.java:43)
    at com.test.client.GwtTest$1.run(GwtTest.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.ExceptionHelper.runProtected(ExceptionHelper.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleFeatureType$.register(MapTypeStyleFeatureType.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleFeatureType$.create(MapTypeStyleFeatureType.java)
    at com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleFeatureType$.&lt;clinit&gt;(MapTypeStyleFeatureType.java:39)
    at com.test.client.GwtTest.createMap(GwtTest.java:43)
    at com.test.client.GwtTest$1.run(GwtTest.java:25)
    at com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.ExceptionHelper.runProtected(ExceptionHelper.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The weird thing is, the Exception seems to be internal to GoogleMaps, so I don't really know what's going on?

Am I doing something obviously dumb with the Styles?

Edit: I've also asked this question on the [GWT Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/pW8B-dSbLHg).

Comment: Fiddling with the source code of the com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeStyleFeatureType, the line where the NPE is thrown seems pretty simple: `registry.put(value.getValue(), value);` It doesn't seem to be the registry variable, it is a static final field. Maybe your `MapTypeStyleFeatureType` value passed as parameter? Can you call getValue() of it and see if returns anything?

Comment: @André Thanks for the reply. I agree that's where the NPE occurs, but it's a little more complicated: that function is called from this static variable initialization on line 38 of MapTypeStyleFeatureType: public static final MapTypeStyleFeatureType ADMINISTRATIVE=create("administrative");. This code is internal to GWT and gets called as soon as I use the MapTypeStyleFeatureType class at all (since static variables are initialized when the class is loaded)! So it even occurs if I just do this without even using the value: Object m = MapTypeStyleFeatureType.ROAD;

Comment: If you can, try submitting this issue at their issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/list 
If simple usage of MapTypeStyleFeatureType throws a NPE, there might be something wrong with their implementation itself :|

Comment: @André Darn, I was hoping I was doing something stupid- maybe something needs initialized first or something. Is there some other way to set styles using GWT? I have a post up on the GWT forum, if I don't get any answers this weekend then I'll file a bug report. But the GoogleMaps GWT API hasn't been updated in almost 3 years, so I'm not holding my breath for a fix.

Comment: I never used the Maps API, but look at this source, I suppose this guy got it working? https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/blob/master/gwt-maps-showcase/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/maps/testing/client/maps/StyledMapWidget.java

Comment: @André Yeah, unfortunately that's an entirely different GoogleMaps API. I'm stuck with the official Google API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67251/discussion-between-andre-and-kevin-workman).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one workaround involving writing native JavaScript that bypasses the GoogleMaps GWT API:

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMap() {

        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mapOpts.setStreetViewControl(false);

        GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);

        styleMap(map);
    }


    public native void styleMap(GoogleMap map) /*-{
        map.set('styles', [
          {
            "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "off" }
            ]
          },{
            "stylers": [
              { "invert_lightness": true }
            ]
          }
        ]);
    }-*/;
}
```

I'd still be curious to find out if there's a pure Java workaround, but if anybody else has this problem, this native approach works. And it has the added bonus that it works directly with JSON you can export from the [GoogleMaps Styling Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).